# Could not import the OpenCV Library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv, module, configuration

I had downloaded the Android Studio 4.0.1 and the same version for OpenCV Library.

I made a random Java project just to set the library, but when I select the library (the path is correct -"C:\opencv-4.0.1-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java") they don't show it and let me finish this action (please see the image below).

[image: Image showing the problem]

Why I can't select the library? I am watching an Youtube video for this (beginner here) and the guy can see it totally different.

Comment: For the future, please see [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select library. Add this module then do this steps:
Open Project Structure-> Dependencies-> app -> Add module dependency-> select opencv module.
You can access opencv classes right now.

[image: How to add module dependency]

Comment: I think the original question was asking for help with the "Add this module" part, and that's the part that needs explaining, not the part about how to add a dependency on the module after it's already added/imported.  The original screenshot comes from doing **File > New > Import Module**.  Notice the correct location is specified, but the _Finish_ and _Next_ buttons are disabled, so the asker cannot proceed to get the module added in the first place.

Comment: How did you get `openCVLibrary342` to appear in that list?  And please pay special attention to the fact that it's version 4.0.1 in the screenshot.  Some things may be different for version 4.

Answer (score 1):

For me the import project functionality also doesn't work, but what worked is to create a new empty project, clears its artifacts, and copy the OpenCV library artifacts from OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\java\ folder. There are 6 steps:

- copy AndroidManifest.xml to src/main
- copy sources to src/main/java
- copy res folder to src/main
- copy libs folder from OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs to src/main and rename it to jniLibs
- create folder src\main\aidl and **move** file src\main\java\org\opencv\engine\OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl to folder src\main\aidl\org\opencv\engine\
- in build.gradle set project as library by specifying plugins { id 'com.android.library'}

You can refer to the image in order to see the final project tree:
[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qclg.png)